# Clearing just cache without removing history, saved credentials

Tags: google-chrome, browser, history, browser-cache

I recently started using Google Chrome browser. It looks good, but I get confused with "Clear browsing data" setting (see image below).

[image]

**My question:** How to I clear only cached files without removing browsing history, saved credentials and most important - without going through login process on each site in my history.

Recently, I cleared "browsing data" using above setting where all the checkboxes were selected (same as in above image) and Somehow, I got logged-out from all sites :(

I had to login in back to Gmail and all other sites.

Also I didn't understand 2 things under "Clear browsing data" settings:

1. What is Hosted app data?
2. What comes under Content licenses?
3. If "download history" is selected(ticked) during removal, does it also remove files from my computer?
4. What does following mean, "Saved content settings and search engines will not be cleared"?

Answer (score 3):

> What is Hosted app data?

Hosted app data refers to data from the apps you’ve added to Chrome
from the Chrome Web Store. For example, the local storage used by
Gmail Offline.

> What comes under Content licenses?

This will prevent Flash Player from playing any previously viewed
protected content, such as movies or music that you’ve purchased. It’s
recommended to deauthorize content licenses before selling or donating
your computer.

> If "download history" is selected(ticked) during removal, does it also remove files from my computer?

No,only the history of files would get cleared and it wont clear the file at your harddrive

> What does following mean, "Saved content settings and search engines will not be cleared"?

Open history.google.com find your content and search engine history, this wont be cleared during this process

To prevent logout you have to keep cookies and Select the checkboxes for only the type of information that you want to remove. Unselect the checkboxes for the information you want to keep.

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply. Looks like you missed an important part of my question.


**My question:** How to I clear only cached files without removing browsing history, saved credentials and most important - without going through login process on each site in my history.

Recently, I cleared "browsing data" using above setting where all the checkboxes were selected (same as in above image) and Somehow, I got logged-out from all sites :(

Comment: @I-M-JM updated the answer with missing part

Answer (score 0):

> I cleared "browsing data" using above setting where all the checkboxes were selected and I got logged-out from all sites

To prevent logout you have to keep cookies.

> How do I clear only cached files without removing browsing history and saved credentials?

Select the checkboxes for only the type of information that you want to remove. Unselect the checkboxes for the information you want to **keep**.

For example, if you just want to delete just the cache:

- leave cache ticked
- untick everything else (if you click on a tick it will remove the tick)

> What is Hosted app data?

Hosted app data is data from apps added to Chrome from the Chrome Web Store, for example the local storage used by Gmail Offline.

> What comes under Content licenses?

Content licences are licences to play protected content such as movies or music that you’ve purchased.

You should remove (deauthorize) content licenses if you want to sell or dispose of your computer.

> If "download history" is selected (ticked) during removal, does it also remove files from my computer?

This is a list of files you've downloaded. The actual files are not removed from your computer.

> What does "Saved content settings and search engines will not be cleared" mean?

Privacy content settings will not be changed.

Search engine settings will not be changed.

**Further reading:** [Delete your cache, history, and other browser data](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95582?p=settings_clear_browsing_data&rd=1)

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply. Didn't get this part though: Select the checkboxes for only the type of information that you want to remove. Unselect the checkboxes for the information you want to keep

Comment: If everything is ticked it will clear everything. If you just want to delete the cache then leave cache ticked and untick everything else (if you click on a tick it will remove the tick)

Comment: @DavidPostill - Does the hosted appdata also compromise of local storage that is used by extensions?

Comment: @AlexS No idea. I know that extension local storage is in `%LocalAppData%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Local Storage` but I'm unable to find where hosted app data is actually stored.